# Is there any open source animation library?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, animation

I want to collect some useful & common animatios in ios.

Is there any open source library or project?

Comment: You need to be more clear about what you mean by "animations". Are you talking about common screen transitions like a wipe from one screen to the next. These are typically called "animations" in iOS circles. Or, are you talking about small videos components that do things in sync but act more like a series of PNG images? Something like a spinning ball animation or a person running made up of multiple animated frames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An excellent open source animation framework is [Sparrow](http://gamua.com/sparrow/) (it's more of a 2D game engine, but it's written in pure objective-c, so you can intermix Sparrow and Cocoa), you may want to have a look at it.

Answer (score 4):

Apple has a few videos from their 2010 WWDC session on animation along with the projects shown. They can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

The ones related to animation are:

- WWDC 2010 Session 123 – Building Animation Driven Interfaces
- WWDC 2010 Session 424 – Core Animation in Practice, Part 1
- WWDC 2010 Session 425 – Core Animation in Practice, Part 2